# View pager not swipe smoothly

Tags: android

Here is my code please check an tell me what is the problem.`fragment` is not swipe smoothly on second swipe mostly. I am checked with `FragmentPagerAdapter` and with Override `getItemPosition()` method but can not find solution.

```
    //View Pager Adapter

public class MyBookingPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    private ArrayList<Booking> bookingList;
    public MyBookingPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,ArrayList<Booking> bookingList) {
        super(fm);
        this.bookingList=bookingList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MyBookingFragment.newInstance(bookingList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bookingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}

//View Pager Fragment

public class MyBookingFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private Booking booking;
    private RelativeLayout containerTopView;
    private TextView txtTitle,txtAddress,txtDay,txtMonth,txtShowDayName,txtShowDate,txtLastEntyTime,txtFemalesprice,txtCouplePrice,txtMalesPrice,txtTotalAmount;
    private ImageView imgTopView;
    private LinearLayout dotsContainer;

    public static MyBookingFragment newInstance(Booking booking){
        MyBookingFragment fragmentMyBooking= new MyBookingFragment();
        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("booking",booking);
        fragmentMyBooking.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentMyBooking;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_booking_appbar,container,false);
        //      init Layout view (find View By Id from the xml)
        initViews(view);

        //      Set booking values of views
        if(booking!=null)
            setValues(booking);
        return view;
    }



    private void setValues(Booking booking) {
        txtTitle.setText(booking.getEventName());
        txtAddress.setText(booking.getAddress());
        txtShowDayName.setText(booking.getDayName());
        txtShowDate.setText(booking.getBookingDate());
        txtLastEntyTime.setText(booking.getBookingTime());
        txtFemalesprice.setText(booking.getFemale()+" x +getString(R.string.Rs)+booking.getLaydiesPrice());
        txtMalesPrice.setText(booking.getMale()+" x "+getString(R.string.Rs)+booking.getStageEntryPrice());
        txtCouplePrice.setText(booking.getCouple()+" x "+getString(R.string.Rs)+booking.getCouplePrice());
        txtTotalAmount.setText(booking.getTotalPrice());
        try{
      ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(booking.getImgTopView(),imgTopView);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Utils.print("MyBookingFragment ImageLoader",e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {
        txtShowDayName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyBookingShowDay);
        txtShowDate= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyBookingShowDate);
        txtLastEntyTime= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyBookingLastEntryTime);
        txtFemalesprice= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyBookingFemalePrice);
        txtMalesPrice= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyBookingMalesPrice);
        txtCouplePrice= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyBookingCouplePrice);
        txtTotalAmount= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyBookingTotal);
        txtAddress= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyBookingAddress);
        txtTitle= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyBookingTitle);
        imgTopView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTopView);
        containerTopView= (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.containerTopView);
        booking= (Booking) getArguments().getSerializable("booking");
    }

}

//Setting View Pager Adapter

                    adapter=new MyBookingPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),bookingArrayList);
                    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
                    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);



                    //      showing no data msg view
                    if(adapter.getCount()<=0)
                        findViewById(R.id.frameNoData).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else{
                        setIndicators(bookingArrayList.size());
                        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
                            @Override
                            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                                if(indicators!=null)
                                    indicators[position].setChecked(true);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { } });
```

Comment: may be any memory problem, try in another device with good specifications, and solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your custom `ViewPager` class:

```
public class ViewPagerCustomDuration extends ViewPager {

public ViewPagerCustomDuration(Context context) {
    super(context);
    scrollInitViewPager();
}

public ViewPagerCustomDuration(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    scrollInitViewPager();
}

private ScrollerCustomDuration mScroller = null;

private void scrollInitViewPager() {
    try {
        Field scroller = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        scroller.setAccessible(true);
        Field interpolator = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator");
        interpolator.setAccessible(true);
        mScroller = new ScrollerCustomDuration(getContext(), (Interpolator) interpolator.get(null));
        scroller.set(this, mScroller);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

**ScrollerCustomDuration.Java**

```
public class ScrollerCustomDuration extends Scroller {

private double mScrollFactor = 1;

public ScrollerCustomDuration(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ScrollerCustomDuration(Context context, Interpolator interpolator) {
    super(context, interpolator);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public ScrollerCustomDuration(Context context, Interpolator interpolator, boolean flywheel) {
    super(context, interpolator, flywheel);
}

/**
 * Set the factor by which the duration will change
 */
public void setScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
    mScrollFactor = scrollFactor;
}

@Override
public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
    super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, (int) (duration * mScrollFactor));
}

}
```

Now in your xml file use `ViewPagerCustomDuration` instead of default `ViewPager`.

Comment: what about ScrollerCustomDuration, is it any Custom class ?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention. Just check my edit. For more smooth scrolling you can increase scrollfactor variable.

Comment: nothing improve (mostly on second or third swipe it skip the fragment swipe otherwise working fine)

Comment: then you should set `mpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` in ur code

Comment: yes i have checked with mpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); and mpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);but not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating view every time in `onCreateView()`. Please save your view in a global view variable and use that one.

```
View  view;
in onCreateView()
// 
if(view=null){
view=infla ter.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_booking_appbar,container,false);
}
```

Please check if you are creating new fragment every time, Please give your fragment a tag and get the fragment from FragmentManager via tag.